# Java NIO Selector Hang (jdk1.6_20)

Tags: java, nio

I'm using `jdk1.6_20` on `Linux 2.6`. I am observing a behavior where the NIO Selector, after calling `Selector.select(timeout)`, fails to wake-up within the timeout(`timeout=5 sec`). It returns much later, couple of seconds delay(2~10 seconds) . This seems to be happening frequently during initial couple of minutes of application start-up time and stabilizes later on. Since our server is heart-beating with the client, the selector failing to wake-up on time causes it miss heartbeat and the peer disconnecting us.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it seems to me quite a bad idea to have a server/client heart-beating together.

Comment: why heartbeating is bad idea ..it is defined as part of the connectivity protocol.

Comment: I'm not expert and I'd like to see the opinion of someone who knows more than me, but it seems like it's not how server/client should be set up.  It looks unnatural.  You're having problems now and I would bet you'll just have more problems in the future.

Comment: you dont realise we need to connect to a proprietary system through proprietary protocol..not sure if you have heard about fix protocol ..but it is similiar ..heartbeating is not an option for us ..we have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm... actually the story doesnt stop there ..we are not using incremental cms ..hence during the concurrent phase it is not relinquishing the cpu ... we are having 2 application servers on the same host with 16 cores and each is having 4 Parallel CMS threads besides the application threads of which there are about roughtly 45 to 60. Hence chances of CPU starvation are the most likely especially since we see that every time the selector gets delayed it is 100~200 milliseconds immediately after the concurrent-mark phase..

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for [`Selector.select(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28long%29):

> This method does not offer real-time guarantees: It schedules the
>   timeout as if by invoking the Object.wait(long) method.

Since startup time for an application might put a lot of stress on a system, this may lead to wakeup-delays.

For a solution: Switch to [`Selector.selectNow()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectNow%28%29) as a non-blocking operation and handle retries in your application code.

Comment: hmm.. can you explain more on the stress ...is it jvm trying to optimize the code in background ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the `timeout` is, as soon as a client is connecting, the selector should wake up immediately. Therefore you have some more serious bugs.

Comment: actually the client is already connected . It does a Selector.select(timeout) to block until the next time to send a heartbeat.

Comment: It should wakeup as soon as the TCP stack responds and then the thread sheduler permits. There is nothing guaranteed to be 'immediate' about either.

Answer (score 0):

> fails to wake-up within the timeout(timeout=5 sec).

It's not supposed to 'wake-up within the timeout'. It is supposed to wakeup *after the timeout expires.* If you're supposed to send heartbeats within 5 seconds, a timeout of 5 seconds is too long. I would make it 2.5s in this case.

Comment: hmmm...actually i understand that ..our heartbeat interval is 5 sec and heartbeat timeout is 10 sec .. the delays in waking up is from 2 to 10 sec roughly so even if i put 2.5 sec , that may not fully solve my problem ..what is interesting is that this delay occurs for initial  5 mins to 10 mins and then it stop i.e there is no delay in the thread waking up after the timeout .. i am wondering if the jvm is doing something during that time which is causing this ..

Comment: @user882659 you would have to show us some code I think. I've never seen this and I've been using NIO since it first came out.

Comment: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1539966  ..i think i may be facing similiar issue..i see long concurrent-mark phase which i guess is starving my application thread

Comment: also check this about jit compilation --http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/did%5Fyou%5Fknow

Comment: @user882659 these are both irrelevant for the reasons given in the final answer to the Oracle thread. GC is concurrent: it won't delay execution of a Selector.

Comment: hmm... actually the story doesnt stop there ..we are not using incremental cms ..hence during the concurrent phase it is not relinquishing the cpu ... we are having 2 application servers on the same host with 16 cores and each is having 4 Parallel CMS threads besides the application threads of which there are about roughtly 45  to 60. Hence chances of CPU starvation are the most likely especially since we see that every time the selector gets delayed it is 100~200 milliseconds immediately after the concurrent-mark phase..